# Questions about ArrayList

Tags: java

I need to use an `ArrayList`, but I am not sure how to do some of these things that would be possible with a normal array.

1) This:

```
int[][] example1 = new int[10][20];
```

(An array with two arguments (10, 20)) is possible with normal arrays, but how to do it with an `ArrayList`.)

2) How to increase the value of an int on the list by 1, like this:

```
example2[3][4] ++;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayList` is dynamically growable list backed by array.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<>>(10);
```

you can get an element of list by `List#get`.

```
List<Integer> innerList = list.get(3);
Integer integer = innerList.get(4);
```

Update value by `List#set` -

```
list.get(3).set(4,list.get(3).get(4)++);
```

NOTE : `Integer` class is immutable.

Comment: Your awesome! Good Stuff

Answer (score 1):

To mimic a multidimensional array using collections you would use:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Java 7

List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); //Pre Java 7
```

So lets say we create a `List<List<Integer>>` where the outer `List` contains 10 `List<Integer>` and the inner list contains 10 `Integer`s.  To set the fifth element on the fourth list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        List<Integer> inner = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        outer.add(inner);
    }
    //Remember that Integer is immutable
    outer.get(3).set(4, new Integer(outer.get(3).get(4)) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `int[][] example1 = new int[10][20];`
    you can do it in arraylist by using this syntax :

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ex = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

1. `example2[3][4] ++;` 
    This can be same in arraylist as by using this :

`int val = (a.get(0).get(0)) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your declaration with an `ArrayList` is:

```
List<List<Integer>> example1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

You have to use `Integer` because Java Collections do not support primitive types. Check out [this page of the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more information on Autoboxing and Unboxing.

Since an `ArrayList`can grow dynamically, you don't need to give a size. If you want it to have an initial size, you can pass that as an argument to the constructor.

You can get elements from an `ArrayList` (or any Class implementing the `List` interface) by using the `get()` method with the index of the element as an argument.

Using `example.get()` on `example1` will give you an object of the type `List`. You can then use `get()` again to get an `Integer`.